# Unable to send emails from one particular page

Tags: php, swiftmailer

Using swiftmailer, I'm able to send mails in various other pages in my server, but one particular page doesn't send the mails and doesn't throw any error message. This page did send emails for at least 100 of them and then stopped working. Is it something to do with Google's Mailing Policy? All the mails I sent were from my Organisation's email ID, and mails were sent only to an ID within the Organisation. I'm unable to figure out what went wrong. I have no error messages to show either.

Comment: Nothing in the logs? You would need to share some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  There is almost nothing here for anyone to go on.  Is the code the same between all pages?  What triggers the mails being sent?  Have you checked your logs?  Spam folder?  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).